# MultiDex.install only on some product flavor

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I need to call MultiDex.install inside "attachBaseContext" but only for debug builds and for a single flavor (api level < 21).

Currently i have in my build.gradle the dependencies like this:

```
debugCompile deps.support.multidex
icsCompile deps.support.multidex
```

What is the best way to call MultiDex.install for only these flavors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check `BuildConfig` values in `attachBaseContext`:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
   super.attachBaseContext(base);
   if (BuildConfig.DEBUG || BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("flavorName")) {
      MultiDex.install(this);
   }
}
```

Comment: I know that i can do something like this but the multidex dependency isn't available for all flavors. As a workaround i'm calling "MultiDex.install" with reflection to avoid build errors with other flavors

Comment: Add `provided files('libs/multidex-1.0.1.jar')` to dependencies (download this jar manually). This makes it available at compile-time.